# GridAdapter array out of bounds?

Tags: android

I am having a problem with GridAdapter for Andorid gridview. The error is "12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{btn.grid/btn.grid.ButtonGridActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
"

and the adapter is

```
 package btn.grid;



import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;

class MonthAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private GregorianCalendar mCalendar;
        private Calendar mCalendarToday;
        private Context mContext;
        private DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics;
        private List<String> mItems;
        private int mMonth;
        private int mYear;
        private int mDaysShown;
        private int mDaysLastMonth;
        private int mDaysNextMonth;
        private int mTitleHeight, mDayHeight;
        private final String[] mDays = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
        private final int[] mDaysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

        public MonthAdapter(Context c, int month, int year ) {
                mContext = c;
                mMonth = month;
                mYear = year;
                mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(mYear, mMonth, 1);
                mCalendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();

                populateMonth();
        }

        private void populateMonth() {
                mItems = new ArrayList<String>();              
                for (String day : mDays) {
                        mItems.add(day);
                        mDaysShown++;
                }

                int firstDay = getDay(mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
                int prevDay;
                if (mMonth == 0)
                        prevDay = daysInMonth(11) - firstDay + 1;
                else
                        prevDay = daysInMonth(mMonth - 1) - firstDay + 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < firstDay; i++) {
                        mItems.add(String.valueOf(prevDay + i));
                        mDaysLastMonth++;
                        mDaysShown++;
                }

                int daysInMonth = daysInMonth(mMonth); 
                for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                        mItems.add(String.valueOf(i));
                        mDaysShown++;
                }

                mDaysNextMonth = 1;
                while (mDaysShown % 7 != 0) {
                        mItems.add(String.valueOf(mDaysNextMonth));
                        mDaysShown++;
                        mDaysNextMonth++;
                }

                mTitleHeight = 30;
                int rows = (mDaysShown / 7);
                mDayHeight = (mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels - mTitleHeight
                                - (rows * 3) - getBarHeight())/ (rows - 1);
        }

        private int daysInMonth(int month) {
                int daysInMonth = mDaysInMonth[month];
                if (month == 1 && mCalendar.isLeapYear(mYear))
                        daysInMonth++;
                return daysInMonth;
        }

        private int getBarHeight() {
                switch (mDisplayMetrics.densityDpi) {
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                        return 48;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                        return 32;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                        return 24;
                default:
                        return 48;
                }
        }

        /**
         * For week starting Monday
         * @param day from Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK
         * @return day week starting Monday
         */
        private int getDay(int day) {
                switch (day) {
                case Calendar.MONDAY:
                        return 0;
                case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                        return 1;
                case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                        return 2;
                case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                        return 3;
                case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                        return 4;
                case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                        return 5;
                case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                        return 6;
                default:
                        return 0;
                }
        }

        private boolean isToday(int day, int month, int year) {
                if (mCalendarToday.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month
                                && mCalendarToday.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year
                                && mCalendarToday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == day) {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final TextView view = new TextView(mContext);
                view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                view.setText(mItems.get(position));
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(244, 244, 244));
                view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                if (position <= 6) {
                        // names
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 10, 80, 255));
                        view.setHeight(mTitleHeight);
                } else if (position <= mDaysLastMonth + 6) {
                        // previous month
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(234, 234, 245));
                        view.setHeight(mDayHeight);
                } else if (position <= mDaysShown - mDaysNextMonth  ) {
                        // current month
                        view.setHeight(mDayHeight);
                        int day = position - (mDaysLastMonth + 6);
                        if (isToday(day, mMonth, mYear)) {
                                view.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                        // check db and colour for shifts
                        // ...
                } else {
                        // next month
                        view.setHeight(mDayHeight);
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(234, 234, 245));
                }
                return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return mItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
                return mItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
        }
}
```

*LogCat

```
    12-28 21:35:44.873: W/dalvikvm(370): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{btn.grid/btn.grid.ButtonGridActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at btn.grid.MonthAdapter.daysInMonth(MonthAdapter.java:82)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at btn.grid.MonthAdapter.populateMonth(MonthAdapter.java:62)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at btn.grid.MonthAdapter.<init>(MonthAdapter.java:40)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at btn.grid.ButtonGridActivity.onCreate(ButtonGridActivity.java:16)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-28 21:35:44.893: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: If you can post some more stack trace, that would be great. The stack trace you provided right now is not showing up any line numbers and your code posting is little bit bigger to go through.

Comment: Can you do System.out.println() for mMonth right before these lines in populateMonth() method   :  if (mMonth == 0)
                        prevDay = daysInMonth(11) - firstDay + 1;
                else
                        prevDay = daysInMonth(mMonth - 1) - firstDay + 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your added stracktrace, you can see the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` originates from line 82. That means that the following results in the exception:

```
int daysInMonth = mDaysInMonth[month];
```

In other words, an invalid index is used for the lookup in the `mDaysInMonth`; probably `month > 11` although it could potentially also be negative.

`month` is the parameter you're passing to:

```
private int daysInMonth(int month)
```

The call to this method resulting in the exception came from line 62:

```
int daysInMonth = daysInMonth(mMonth);
```

That means that `mMonth` is an invalid index for the eventual array lookup. Since `mMonth` is being initialised in the constructor of the adapter, you'd better check the value you're passing it at the moment you create your `MonthAdapter`.

```
public MonthAdapter(Context c, int month, int year ) {
    (...)
    mMonth = month;
    (...)
}
```